# How to translate to a language different than the current one?

Tags: translation, multi-language

I have a problem. Site in English, with serveral languages. Say I'm in an Italian page, but I want certain phrases to be translated in French, for example.
Currently using standard .po files. I need somthing  like (fictional code) `__('my string', 'lang', 'textdomain')`. In other words, I would like to use some function that lets me translate to another language than the current one. Or, to say in other words, a way to make wordpress use another .mo file, other than the current one, only for certain strings where needed. How to?

Comment: do you have an example of why you might want to translate your sites strings to one language, but translate specific strings into another? What's the use case for this? The `__` API is for translating static strings, the idea that it would translate into multiple languages on the same request isn't what it was built for and strongly implies it's being misused or misunderstood. The `.mo`/`.po` file maps the string in the template to what it should appear as for users browsing in that language

Comment: Simply, for our target, we don't want and don't need to translate in english all the strings. I'll end up putting some french in the italian .po.

Comment: That is probably the solution, e.g if one your static UI phrases is a sentence like this “the word for hello in French is bonjour” then you would put in your po what that sentence is for each language, even if it includes a portion that is identical. It’s not necessarily about the translation itself, it’s about what people with that locale are meant to be show . Note that this API is intended for static UI strings, never dynamic variables or strings from the database or files or variables

Comment: Note that you’re still using a very very vague example which makes it really difficult to answer the question! I know it seems simple to state the question as you have but it’s not as simple, there’s nuance. A concrete specific example will help enormously and save a lot of time